# mysql query to get count of products along with quantity

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT product,quantity,count(product) AS count 
  FROM order_table WHERE order_id in
   (select order_id from progress) 
group by product
```

using this query i get product name and count of products. but, i also have quantity column in my table. so, when product gets 2 quantity how to add that quantity along with product count with this above query.

in the above image there are 3 burger products and 2 quantity for one burger product, here i need to show like product : burger and total quantity : 4 later in next line product : pizza and total quantity : 3

Comment: remove `group by product`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT product,sum(quantity)as 'quantity',count(product) AS count 
  FROM order_table WHERE order_id in
   (select order_id from progress) 
group by product

Just a use aggrigate function sum on quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Need some sample data. Input data and expected output.
Till then try it out this query --

```
SELECT Product
    ,SUM(Quantity) AS Total_Quantity
    ,COUNT(Product) AS Product_Count
FROM order_table
WHERE order_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT order_id
        FROM Progress
    )
GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: It's just a basic GROUP BY. In simple words, if your select statement has some columns which are not involved in some aggregation like SUM, AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN functionality then you should mention those columns in your GROUP BY clause. 

And in WHERE clause I just selected the DISTINCT i.e. unique Order_Id from Progress table.

Don't forget to mark it as an answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data it is difficult to guess, but looking at your question, looks like you need something like this

```
SELECT product
 ,sum(quantity) as total_quantity
 ,count(*) AS count 
  FROM order_table 
 WHERE order_id in
   (select order_id from progress) 
group by product
```

Comment: i should get both the product and quantity results in combined

Comment: Update your question. Give your sample data and expected output and tell why this query is not giving you that.

Comment: i am getting the results what i needed 'SELECT product,sum(quantity) as total_quantity,count(product) AS count  FROM order_table  WHERE order_id in
  (select order_id from progress) group by product

Comment: but i don't know how this query is working can you please explain me

Comment: When you group by any column, you will get only 1 row returned for that column. For other columns, you have to perform any aggregate function. So `count` will count the number of rows in that group. And sum(quantity) will add all the quantity in that group. Hence the output.

Comment: If the query is giving you expected output, then accept the answer so the question could be closed. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers